# OnClickListener not triggered as parameter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set OnClickListener as parameter inside my setOnBackButtonClickListener method.Already created object of listener and set it as parameter inside my method, but OnClickListener is not trigered.

When I do Log, method is called, but it does not triger listener.

I suppose that this is because of Fragment LifeCycle.

Here is my OnClickListener:

```
 @Bind(R.id.action_bar) ActionBar actionBar;

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    View.OnClickListener clickL = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            navigateTo(LoginActivity.class);
        }
    };
```

Here is method call inside onViewCreated:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        actionBar.setOnBackButtonClickListener(clickL);
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind your OnClickListener as a variable in your layout and assign it to your view.

What I usually do with a fragment is have it implement `View.OnClickListener`, and then bind the fragment to the layout.

**Layout: frag_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="fragment"
            type="au.com.myapp.fragments.BaseFragment"/>
    </data>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_undo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/AppTheme.TextView"
        android:text="UNDO"
        android:onClickListener="@{fragment}"/>

</layout>
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        FragTestBinding binding = FragTestBinding.inflate(inflater);

        // Set the layout's "fragment" variable so that this fragment handles the onClick.
        binding.setFragment(this);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.tv_undo:
                // Your code in response to the click.
                break;
        }
    }
}
```